# How far could the Airbus A321XLR actually fly commercially?

Tags: range

Airbus [states](https://www.airbus.com/aircraft/passenger-aircraft/a320-family/a321neo.html)

> It will offer even more range – up to 4,700 nm (8,700 km) – in a comfortable 2-class layout

There is an animation which contains this:

[image]

And that is [4735 miles](http://www.gcmap.com/dist?P=dxb-cpt&DU=mi&DM=&SG=&SU=mph). So now I am intensely curious what's actually possible.

Comment: The question is too general, what do you mean by "fly commercially"? Any airplane can fly farther with no payload than it can with a large payload, but the payload at which the flight is commercially viable will depend on the costs and revenues for that specific flight. There may also be difficult to quantify business factors such as the marketing benefit of holding a best in class title, or customer loyalty derived from more profitable routes that connect to this long route.

Comment: Well, I mean, not a test flight but something they could actually market and sell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Airbus is quoting the ranges in nautical miles (nm) which is typical for aircraft. The Great Circle Mapper you linked is using statute miles, which are shorter. If you switch it to be in nautical miles, [you get 4115 nm,](http://www.gcmap.com/dist?P=dxb-cpt&DU=nm&DM=&SG=&SU=mph) which is well within the quoted range.

Comment: *facepalm* SI for the win, thanks!